# MS Access form not updating with latest data

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

The MS Access frontend is linked to an SQL server backend. I've created a new view in the backend called 'v_Report', whose definition is:

```
SELECT r.*
[some other stuff]
FROM tblReport r
LEFT JOIN [some other stuff]
```

I then made a new form (frmTest) for testing purposes, with a single textbox (txtFilepath). I set the form recordsource to 'v_Report' and made a textbox on the form with the control source 'Filepath'.

The textbox works fine the first time the form is opened. However, when I update the data from the backend, the form textbox doesn't show the updated text after toggling between design view and form view. It's not until I restart MS Access that the textbox finally updates.

I've tried restarting the PC, but no effect. I've checked that tblReport has a primary key, and I've made sure to assign a unique record identifier to the view.

Any ideas for why it's broken?

To be explicit, here is a list of steps and observations:

1. In backend, run the following: `UPDATE tblReport SET Filepath = 'abc'` (note for testing purposes tblReport has only 1 row)
2. Open MS Access, open frmTest. Observe that txtFilepath reads 'abc'.
3. In backend, run the following: `UPDATE tblReport SET Filepath = 'def'` (Or alternatively, open v_Report in datasheet view in MS Access and update Filepath there)
4. In MS Access, switch frmTest to design view and then back to form view. Observe that txtFilepath reads 'abc'. (As a side note: Opening v_Report or tblReport in datasheet view here accurately shows that Filepath = 'def')
5. Close and reopen MS Access. Open frmTest in form view. Observe that txtFilepath reads 'def'.

Unfortunately I'm not able to share any files. Both the frontend and backend of the database contain sensitive information.

Comment: Nothing is broken. _Requery_ the form or the textbox.

Comment: ^this. Shift+F9 or `Me.Requery` in VBA. Actually, to update existing record on the form, Refresh should be enough (F9 or `Me.Refresh`).

Comment: Thanks @Gustav. Any way to detect whether the form needs a requery? I thought that checking Me.Dirty would be sufficient, which is why I didn't think to requery.

Comment: `Me.Dirty` detects what the form does, not what happens in the backend. And @Andre is probably right, that only a `Refresh` is needed.